# How to use multiple conditions in Openerp workflow transitions?

Tags: xml, odoo, openerp-7

I am currently working on hr_holidays work-flow and I need to call a sub flow according to multiple conditions in one transitions. This is what I have written so far.

Flag fields from **hr_holidays** class

```
 #flags for use workflow in different levels
        'flag_sub':fields.boolean('Substitute'),
        'flag_manager':fields.boolean('Manager'),
        'flag_gm':fields.boolean('GM'),
```

Transition from **hr_holidays_workflow.xml**

```
<record model="workflow.transition" id="holiday_confirm2validate"> <!-- 2. submitted->accepted (validate signal) if not double_validation-->
        <field name="act_from" ref="act_confirm" />
        <field name="act_to" ref="act_new_validate1" />
        <field name="signal">validate</field>
        <field name="condition">**not sub_flag and not flag_manager and not flag_gm**</field>
        <field name="group_id" ref="base.group_hr_user"/>
    </record>
```

Please help me with writing these conditions